# Animating component with ReactCSSTransitionGroup

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactcsstransitiongroup

I am trying to animate modal on button click with ReactCSSTransitionGroup. Right now, modal appears on button click but without transition. My render method looks like this:

```
render() {
return (
  <div>
    <button onClick={this.handleModOpen}>show modal</button>

    <ReactCSSTransitionGroup
      transitionName="modal"
      transitionEnterTimeout={500}
      transitionLeaveTimeout={300}
    >
      <Modal
        show={this.state.isOpen}
        onClose={this.handleModClose}
      >
        Hello user(187-5451-32)!
      </Modal>
    </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
  </div>
);
```

}

and here's css

```
.modal-enter {
  opacity: 0.01;
}

.modal-enter.modal-enter-active {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: 500ms ease-in;
}

.modal-leave {
  opacity: 1;
}

.modal-leave.modal-leave-active {
  opacity: 0.01;
  transition: 300ms ease-in;
}
```

what am I doing wrong? or should i do it different way, any recommendation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to conditionally render the modal component within the transition group. It only transitions the addition and subtraction of elements from the dom. So something like this:

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={this.handleModOpen}>show modal</button>

      <ReactCSSTransitionGroup
        transitionName="modal"
        transitionEnterTimeout={500}
        transitionLeaveTimeout={300}
      >
        {this.state.isOpen &&

          <Modal
            show={true}
            onClose={this.handleModClose}
          >
            Hello user(187-5451-32)!
          </Modal>

        }
      </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
    </div>
  );
}
```

This renders the `show={true}` prop on the modal obsolete.